# QGIS Shapefile edited by multiple users

Tags: qgis, shapefile, performance, database, server

I have a Vector layer containing 36000+ line Objects with a large number of attributes that is currently saved as Shapefile on a server (local network).

Multiple users access and edit this Layer from different computers in the local network via the attribute table. The workflow seems to get slower  as soon as more than one person works with the layer.

- Is a shapefile the right solution for multiuser access?
- Where to save the Layer and in what format?

Comment: all editing same file ? that may cause some problems with file locking. I would just create simple PostGIS server and spatial data from there. That way you dont get problems with filelocking etc..

Comment: Shapefile is **not** a multiuser file format. You risk catastrophic data loss with every edit. Networked file access is measurably slower than local file access. Database access is generally slower than local file access.  However, actual results are *completely* dependent on local implementation details.

Comment: I will have a look into setting up the shapefile as a database, thanks to  both of you for the warning. Will edit/delete the question when done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to simplexio and Vince for their useful comments leading to this answer:

Shapefile is **not** a multiuser file format and  multiuser access leads to a range of problems beginning with slow access due to file locking problems up to massive data loss.

Its recommended to set up a database-server (eg PostGIS) The data is then streamed to Q-GIS for multiuser access.

I did this and not only does it prevent losing the work of days but it speeds up the process for all the users in my case.